# Print time-related strings like "today" and "yesterday" translated depending on Locale?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-format

I am looking for a way to print time-related strings like "Today" and "Yesterday" translated to the user's Locale (i.e language) in an Android app.

I have tried to use [DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getrelativedatetimestring) but it
does not consider the locale, or at least it is not possible to change it during runtime. I would need something similar to this existing constructor of SimpleDateFormat:

```
public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)
```

Of course, it would be possible to add translations of each word in every language but isn't there a better way assuming the words actually exists in the OS.

Is there a way to achieve this?

**Edit:** 
I am trying to do something similar to the date picker on iOS: 
[image]

Comment: You might also consider my lib [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) which contains translations for "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow" in 88 languages, see also the example given in [API doc](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html#printRelative-net.time4j.base.UnixTime-net.time4j.tz.Timezone-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Comment: Thanks @MenoHochschild, you're a legend!

Comment: @OleV.V. That deleted answer is probably deleted because words like today and yesterday isn't included in the prettytime.

Comment: Sounds like a probable explanation, @HenningHall. Thanks (for repeating what you already said as a comment to the answer so that I too may finally understand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @Meno Hochschild' comment I was able to solve it by:

1. Adding the [Time4A library](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A).
2. Made a local copy of [UnitPatterns.java](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A/blob/master/time4j-android/src/main/java/net/time4j/UnitPatterns.java) and made it public.
3. Used it like this:

`UnitPatterns.of(locale).getTodayWord(); // returns "today"`
`UnitPatterns.of(locale).getYesterdayWord(); // returns "yesterday"`

Comment: Now I have released Time4A-v3.43-2018e which contains direct support via: `PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).printYesterday()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a translation problem,
not a date-format problem.

Your app will have messages that it wants to display to the user.
These messages will need to be translated into your target languages.
Once you know the message you want to display,
retrieve then display the localized (i.e. translated) message using the locale (Android supports that).

It is likely that you do you actually want to display the word "tomorrow" or "yesterday".
Instead,
you probably want to display something like "blah blah tomorrow" or
"sorry blah blah yesterday".
Translate the entire message,
not just the words individually.

**Additional Info**
I think you do need to translate "Today" into every target language.
And, you need to translate each of the date related strings into every target language (by which I mean "Tue May 1" needs to be translated into every language).
There are "tricks" you can use.
Choose the "base" part of the string and use placeholders for the other parts.
Placeholders,
because different languages may have different orders for
"Day-of-week Month Day"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case it's actually only the string "Today" by its own that is going to be displayed, I updated my question with my actual use case. So I still have to add manual translations you believe?